# changing formatting on an access form from a global sub

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am somewhat new to vba, and I'm trying to create a somewhat more complex conditional format than access 2013 allows from the conditional formatting menu. I have a form with 22 target date and actual date fields. for each pair I need to:

if the target date is more than 7 days in the future, color it green.
If the target date is less than 7 days in the future or is today, color it yellow
If the target date in the past, color it red.

UNLESS there is an actual date it was accomplished, in which case:

If the actual date is before the target date, color both dates green
If the actual date is after the target date, color both dates red.

Because I have to do this on form load, and on the change of any date field (the target dates are calculated, but will change if other data is changed in the form), I wanted to write a public sub that takes form name, target date, and actual date as variables. I was able to code each box to do this on the local form module with 'Me.txtbox'
However, when I try to reference the form and text boxes from the public sub, it seems like I'm not properly referencing the text boxes on the form. I've tried 3 or 4 different ways of doing this (string, textbox.name, etc) and I feel like I'm close, but ...

Code that works as desired in the form module

```
Private Sub txtFreqReqDate_AfterUpdate()
  If Me.txtFreqReqDate <= Me.txtFreqReq Then
    Me.txtFreqReq.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[green]"
    Me.txtFreqReqDate.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[green]"
  ElseIf Me.txtFreqReqDate > Me.txtFreqReq Then
    Me.txtFreqReq.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[red]"
    Me.txtFreqReqDate.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[red]"
  ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtFreReqDate) = True Then
    If Me.txtFreqReq < Now() Then
      Me.txtFreqReq.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[red]"
     ElseIf Me.txtFreqReq >= (Now()+7) Then
      Me.txtFreqReq.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[yellow]"
     ElseIf Me.txtFreqReq > (Now()+7) Then
      Me.txtFreqReq.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[green]"
     Else
      Me.txtFreqReq.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[black]"
    End If
  Else
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

Perhaps not the prettiest, but I'm always open to constructive criticism. I'd have to write this 22+ times for each pair, changing the name of the text boxes each time. I want to write a public sub that just takes the names of the text boxes, but I can't seem to find the right combination:

```
Private Sub txtFreqReqDate_AfterUpdate()
  FormatBoxes(Me, me.txtFreqReqDate, me.txtFreqReq)
End Sub
```

And in another module:

```
Public Sub FormatBoxes(CurrentForm As Form, txtActual as Textbox, txtTarget as Textbox)

frmName = CurrentForm.name
tbActual = txtActual.Name
tbTarget = txtTarget.Name


  If frmName.tbActual <= frmName.tbTarget Then
    frmName.tbTarget.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[green]"
    frmName.tbActual.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[green]"
  ElseIf frmName.tbActual > frmName.tbTarget Then
    frmName.tbTarget.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[red]"
    frmName.tbActual.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[red]"
  ElseIf IsNull(frmName.tbActual) = True Then
    If frmName.tbTarget < Now() Then
      frmName.tbTarget.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[red]"
     ElseIf frmName.tbTarget >= (Now()+7) Then
      frmName.tbTarget.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[yellow]"
     ElseIf frmName.tbTarget > (Now()+7) Then
      frmName.tbTarget.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[green]"
     Else
      frmName.tbTarget.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[black]"
    End If
  Else
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

Sorry if this is a bit long, I'm just at my wit's end...

Also, apologies for any typos. I had to re-type this from another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the textbox parameters directly in your sub.

It is not even necessary to pass the form as parameter.

```
Public Sub FormatBoxes(txtActual as Textbox, txtTarget as Textbox)

  If txtActual.Value <= txtTarget.Value Then
      txtTarget.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy[green]"
```

etc.

Note that when calling it, you need either `Call` or remove the parentheses.

```
Private Sub txtFreqReqDate_AfterUpdate()
  Call FormatBoxes(me.txtFreqReqDate, me.txtFreqReq)
  ' or
  ' FormatBoxes me.txtFreqReqDate, me.txtFreqReq
End Sub
```

Comment: Not passing the form name did the trick, actually. I'm guessing the reference to the form must be contained in the textbox object already...?

Comment: @RickDawson, right the textbox objet knows where it's full hierarchy already.

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentForm.name` is a string. It is the `Name` property of the `CurrentForm` object. The `CurrentForm` object also has a controls collection in which the texboxes live. You can refer to them by name in there like `CurrentForm.Controls("tbTarget")` but you can also say `CurrentForm.tbTarget`. So you're very close and on the right track.

Change

```
frmName = CurrentForm.name
tbActual = txtActual.Name
tbTarget = txtTarget.Name
```

to

```
set frmName = CurrentForm
if frmName is not nothing then    
   set tbActual = txtActual
   set tbTarget = txtTarget
end if
```

Alternatively if your signature on your method is

```
Public Sub FormatBoxes(CurrentForm As string, txtActual as string, txtTarget as string)
```

then your set up will look like

```
set frmName = forms(CurrentForm)
if frmName is not nothing then    
   set tbActual = frmName.controls(txtActual)
   set tbTarget = frmName.controls(txtTarget)
end if
```

But I think the first one will work better.

Comment: For some reason, it wasn't working for me in Access 2013, but the rest of your answer is quite helpful.

Comment: Oops, cat on the keyboard. I had to change the 'nothing portion' to 'isnull() =false'. I think the problem was that in passing the form itself, and then the control name, I was somehow logically getting something like 'me.me.txtbox'

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the finished code to help out anyone else who searches for this subject. I did a couple thins to make this sub more universal.
First, Instead of using the date format, I only changed the .ForeColor, allowing me to use this sub for any type of textbox.

```
Public Sub FormatBoxes(txtActual As TextBox, txtTarget As TextBox, chkRequired As CheckBox, _
Optional intOption as Integer)
Dim intRed As Long, intYellow As Long, intGreen As Long, inBlack As Long, intGray As Long
intBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
intGray = RGB(180, 180, 180)
intGreen = RGB (30, 120, 30)
intYellow = RGB(217, 167, 25)
intRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)

If (chkRequired = False) Then 
  txtTarget.ForeColor = intGray
  txtActual.ForeColor = intGray
  If intOption <> 1 Then
   txtTarget.Enabled = False
   txtActual.Enabled = False
   txtTarget.TabStop = False
   txtActual.TabStop = False
  End If
Else
  If intOption <> 1 Then
   txtTarget.Enabled = True
   txtActual.Enabled = True
   txtTarget.Locked = True
   txtActual.Locked = False
   txtTarget.TabStop = False
   txtActual.TabStop = True
  End If
  If IsBlank(txtActual) = True Then
   If txtTarget < Now() Then
    txtTarget.ForeColor = intRed
   ElseIf txtTarget > (Now() + 7) Then
    txtTarget.ForeColor = intGreen
   ElseIf txtTarget >= Now() And txtTarget <= (Now() +7) Then
    txtTarget.ForeColor = intYellow
   Else
    txtTarget.ForeColor = intBlack
   End If
  ElseIf intOption - 1 Then
   txtTarget.ForeColor = intBlack
   txtActual.ForeColor = intBlack
  ElseIf txtActual <= txtTarget Then
   txtTarget.ForeColor = intGreen
   txtActual.ForeColor = intGreen
  ElseIf txtActual > txtTarget Then
   txtTarget.ForeColor = intRed
   txtActual.ForeColor = intRed
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

In case you were wondering, `IsBlank()` is a function that checks for a null or zero length string:

```
Public Function IsBlank(str_in As Variant) As Long
If Len(str_in & "") = 0 Then
  IsBlank = -1
Else
IsBlank = 0
End If
End Function
```

Thanks for all the help, and I hope this is useful for someone.